# Tapping hyperlinked dates in UIWebView in iOS7 shows incorrect dates but not with iOS 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

In my iOS app, the operator enters a birthdate in a datePicker and then several new dates are created from the birthdate with NSDateFormatter of "EEEE, dd MMM yyyy". Using loadHTMLString, the new dates are loaded in a UIWebView. The "Event" property of the UIWebView is checked. In iOS 6, all new dates are shown with hyperlinks and when tapped and the "Create Event" is selected, the correct page of the calendar is opened and there is no error in the debugger output. In iOS 7, the new dates are shown with hyperlinks in the UIWebView but when tapped, the "Create Event" option shows a totally different date from what is shown on the UIWebView. In addition, in iOS 7, some of hyperlinked dates when tapped, a very odd error appears in the debugger output that I can not find it anywhere on the web. Here is the error:

> Unknown DDResult category 1 for result ; could not find any actions for URL x-apple-data-detectors://1

Has anyone seen the above error before?

Here are the screenshots of the app demonstrating the dates before and after being tapped:

[image: screenshot1]
Screenshot1 shows several dates before being tapped. The hyperlinked dates point to the upcoming (future) dates.

[image: screenshot2]
Screenshot2 is taken after the date **10 Feb 2014** was tapped and the "Create Event" option was selected from the pop-up event view controller. As you see the wrong date (14 Oct 2013) is opened in the calendar instead of 10 Feb 2014.

Any idea why the incorrect dates are shown in the calendar with iOS7 but not with iOS6?

Comment: Is your simulator / device's locale set properly? What if you use one of the default NSDateFormatter strings instead of rolling your own?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for your comments. Yes the device and simulator's locale are set properly and I tried some of the default NSDateFormatter strings but I get the same wrong dates. If my setting was incorrect, wouldn't it be also wrong with iOS6? The calculated dates shown in screenshot1 are all correct with both iOS6 and 7 but when a date is tapped, wrong dates are opened in the calendar with iOS7 not with iOS6.

Comment: It sounds like a bug.  The only other thing I could think of that would affect date parsing like this is if the locale was different.  You should file a report on http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @Aaron After contacting the Apple DTS, the engineer also thought that it was a bug in the UIWebView as the UIWebView was caching its data detector results even though the page was reloaded. I have filed a bug report on the website you had referred me to. For now, there is a workaround to resolve the problem which I have posted as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround to resolve the issue with UIWebView in iOS7:

1) turning off data detector for the UIWebView

```
     myWebView.dataDetectorTypes = 0;
```

2) forcing the web view to load a dummy page

```
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><p>clear</p></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

3) some code here to do all the calculations to create new dates and convert them to a HTML string (myHTMLString) and then re-enable the event data detector for the UIWebView

```
    myWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent;
```

4) Now load the UIWebView with the html string which contains the new dates:

```
   [myWebView loadHTMLString:myHTMLString baseURL:nil];
```

The above solution solved my problem.